# Check for Inactivity in a React Native App

Tags: react-native, expo

How do I check for inactivity globally in react native i.e touch events. I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-user-inactivity but it doesn't register touch events. I would prefer pure javascript solutions as apposed to linking native code. A solution for just iOS is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) from react-native package.

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/SyGLEApZb) you can see a working example, using expo toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I created module `react-native-inactivity` for this purpose. By using this module you can actually get if the app is inactive for X ms. You can use in this way.

```js
import ReactNativeInactivity from "react-native-inactivity";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ReactNativeInactivity
        isActive={true}
        onInactive={() => {//Do Logout or something like that}}
        timeForInactivity={60000} //1 mint in ms
        restartTimerOnActivityAfterExpiration={false}
        loop={false}
        style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
        <YOUR_NAV_HERE/>
      </ReactNativeInactivity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can also manage other props according to your requirement.

If this solution helped you just thumbs up and give me a star at repository.
For more refer to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inactivity