# Check Inactivity of React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native

To check the inactivity and do some functions I'm using [react-native-interaction-provider](https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-interaction-provider). Implementation is as below on the Parent Screen.

```
render() {
        return (
            <InteractionProvider
                timeout={AppConfigurations.appInactivityTimeThreshold * 1000}
                onActive={() => this.onNotIdle()}
                onInactive={() => this.onIdle()}
            >
                <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                    /..
                </View>
            </InteractionProvider>
        );
}

onIdle() {
    console.log("MAIN IDLE!");
    this.idleWarningModal.showModal();
}

onNotIdle() {
    console.log("MAIN NOT IDLE!");
}
```

This works fine. The problem arises when you navigate to another view and come back to this parent view, the timer doesn't seem to stop and if the time threshold has been met, the `onIdle` method gets triggered as soon you travel back to the parent screen.

How to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: It's just an idea, but you might use a [service worker](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)? It might help you... but that's pure js and not react

Comment: @Margon Thanks. Will look into this.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78243736/13666027

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the `PanResponder` myself to check for touches in each component. And when traversing to the child view, the parent's `PanResponder` is passed on as `prop` and is set to the child view's `View` component alongside it's own `PanResponder`.

Ex:

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}
                  collapsable={false}
                  {...this.props.mainPagePanResponder.panHandlers}
                  {...this.childPagePanResponder.panHandlers}>
                //Child Content
            </View>
        );
}
```

Not the most sophisticated fix, but works for my instance.

Comment: Hey, i was facing the same issue using this library https://github.com/jkomyno/react-native-user-inactivity, unable to stop the parents inactivity timer when navigated to another screen. Multiple screens inactivities are running all when we keep pushing in navigation stack. Is the Panresponders working well with props to child?